# Scores in json key make jq fail

Tags: key, jq

Having this file,

```
$ cat test.json
{
  "realm": "somerealm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://someserver:8080/auth/"
}
```

How can I get the "auth-server-url" value? This three queries give the same result:

```
$ cat test.json|jq ."auth-server-url"

jq: error: auth/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[auth-server-url]  
jq: error: server/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[auth-server-url]       
jq: error: url/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[auth-server-url]              
jq: 2 compile errors

$ cat test.json|jq .auth-server-url
(similar)

$ cat test.json|jq .["auth-server-url"]
(similar)
```

Please don't tell me to modify the JSON file, it is generated by a known app, Keycloak; I'm using today's jq-1.6 linux binary; the first value goes fine, apparently the error is due to the scores. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `cat test.json | jq '."auth-server-url"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work -

`cat test.json | jq '."auth-server-url"'`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the use of cat, and catch [special characters](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/140) use;

```
jq '.["auth-server-url"]' < test.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue. The problem is not cat, but the undocumented quoting.

Comment: Yea, however, `cat` is unnecessary in your command. Therefore using `<` will improve the speed somehow. ([when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor))